# how to check plugin name unique or not?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wordpress.org

I am new in WordPress but I wanted to know how to check my plugin name is unique or not and how to upload this plugin in wordpress.org. Please guide me how is it possible. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First visit `https://wordpress.org/plugins/yourpluginslug` to see if your desired slug is in use by an existing plugin. If it exists and you don't want to change the name, a -2 will automatically be appended when you submit your plugin and it passes review.

Your plugin must be GPLv2 licenced or GPLv2 compatible and under 25mb when zipped.

Log into your wordpress.org account and submit your plugin [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/developers/add/).

Comment: How to plugin licensing process can you please explain this?

Comment: Here's the GPLv2 licence in plain text: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.txt

Comment: only just added this file in my plugin? or any thing else will do?

Comment: You need to ensure that all code in your plugin is compliant with the licence.

Comment: But how to ensure my code with this license?

Comment: If you wrote it all yourself all you have to do is state in the plugin file's readme.txt that it's released under the GPL. If you're including other people's code you need to check that the licensing doesn't conflict. Best bet would be to ask them if it's not stated anywhere.